# How to put line separators for every lines of text in a paragraph using css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a paragraph with line separators in between the lines of text using css. After doing some research on css I only found text-decoration and `<hr>` tag. None of these will work in my case.

```html
<div  style="text-decoration:underline">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dolor est, condimentum id fringilla eget, vulputate nec odio. Fusce a metus feugiat, euismod urna eu, pretium lacus. Aenean semper sollicitudin felis eget viverra. Mauris feugiat sem non arcu malesuada rhoncus. Sed placerat in dolor eu dignissim. Proin aliquam odio non arcu hendrerit, ut ultrices ex dignissim. Suspendisse convallis ultricies nulla id vehicula. Sed et sem bibendum, 
</div>
```

I do not have any information on number of lines at runtime so I can not use `<hr>` tag.

Desired output:

```
first line of text in a paragraph 
---------------------------------
second line of text in the same p
---------------------------------
third line of text same paragraph
---------------------------------
and so on. End of paragraph.
```

Note that there is no line below the last line of text.

Comment: do you need the container to be responsive or does the container have fixed width?

Comment: I think that the easiest solution is a repetitive background ( width of the dash + white space, height = the line-height css property ). Or look at `text-decoration: overline`

Comment: @iguypouf care to elaborate that a bit with an example? I didn't find this very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background can do this. You simply need to adjust the `line-height` and the `padding-bottom` based on the font you are using

```css
.box span {
  background: linear-gradient(black, black) bottom/100% 1px no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em; /* you may have to adjust this */
}

.box {
  overflow: hidden; /* hide the last line */
  line-height: 1.3em; /* you may have to adjust this */
  /* text-align:justify uncomment this to justify the text*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dolor est, condimentum id fringilla eget, vulputate nec odio. Fusce a metus feugiat, euismod urna eu, pretium lacus. Aenean semper sollicitudin felis eget viverra. Mauris feugiat sem non arcu malesuada rhoncus. Sed placerat in dolor eu dignissim. Proin aliquam odio non arcu hendrerit, ut ultrices ex dignissim. Suspendisse convallis ultricies nulla id vehicula. Sed et sem bibendum, 
</span>
</div>

<div class="box" style="font-size:20px;">
  <span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dolor est, condimentum id fringilla eget, vulputate nec odio. Fusce a metus feugiat, euismod urna eu, pretium lacus. Aenean semper sollicitudin felis eget viverra. Mauris feugiat sem non arcu malesuada rhoncus. Sed placerat in dolor eu dignissim. Proin aliquam odio non arcu hendrerit, ut ultrices ex dignissim. Suspendisse convallis ultricies nulla id vehicula. Sed et sem bibendum, 
</span>
</div>
```

Border can also do the same:

```css
.box span {
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em; /* you may have to adjust this */
}

.box {
  overflow: hidden; /* hide the last line */
  line-height: 1.3em; /* you may have to adjust this */
  /* text-align:justify uncomment this to justify the text*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dolor est, condimentum id fringilla eget, vulputate nec odio. Fusce a metus feugiat, euismod urna eu, pretium lacus. Aenean semper sollicitudin felis eget viverra. Mauris feugiat sem non arcu malesuada rhoncus. Sed placerat in dolor eu dignissim. Proin aliquam odio non arcu hendrerit, ut ultrices ex dignissim. Suspendisse convallis ultricies nulla id vehicula. Sed et sem bibendum, 
</span>
</div>

<div class="box" style="font-size:20px;">
  <span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dolor est, condimentum id fringilla eget, vulputate nec odio. Fusce a metus feugiat, euismod urna eu, pretium lacus. Aenean semper sollicitudin felis eget viverra. Mauris feugiat sem non arcu malesuada rhoncus. Sed placerat in dolor eu dignissim. Proin aliquam odio non arcu hendrerit, ut ultrices ex dignissim. Suspendisse convallis ultricies nulla id vehicula. Sed et sem bibendum, 
</span>
</div>
```

Another idea if you want to span the whole line:

```css
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size:15px;
  line-height: 1.4em; 
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 0 calc(1.4em - 1px), black 0 1.4em)
     0 0/100% calc(100% - 1em);
  /* text-align:justify uncomment this to justify the text*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dolor est, condimentum id fringilla eget, vulputate nec odio. Fusce a metus feugiat, euismod urna eu, pretium lacus. Aenean semper sollicitudin felis eget viverra. Mauris feugiat sem non arcu malesuada rhoncus. Sed placerat in dolor eu dignissim. Proin aliquam odio non arcu hendrerit, ut ultrices ex dignissim. Suspendisse convallis ultricies nulla id vehicula. Sed et sem bibendum, 
</div>

<div class="box" style="font-size:20px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dolor est, condimentum id fringilla eget, vulputate nec odio. Fusce a metus feugiat, euismod urna eu, pretium lacus. Aenean semper sollicitudin felis eget viverra. Mauris feugiat sem non arcu malesuada rhoncus. Sed placerat in dolor eu dignissim. Proin aliquam odio non arcu hendrerit, ut ultrices ex dignissim. Suspendisse convallis ultricies nulla id vehicula. Sed et sem bibendum, 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Javascript. What this does it puts a wrapper span around each row and you are free to style it to your liking

I made it this applies to all paragraphs with the class `paragraph`. The container is what it sounds like, a container for the demo. But I guess you figured that part out.

```js
function wrapLines(element) {
    const container = element
  const spans = container.children
  var top = 0
  var tmp = ''
  const opentag = '<span class="paragraph__inner-text">'
  const closingtag = '</span>'

  container.innerHTML = container.textContent.replace(/\S+/g, '<n>$&</n>')
  for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    const rect = spans[i].getBoundingClientRect().top

    if (top < rect) {
      tmp += closingtag + opentag
    }

    top = rect
    tmp += spans[i].textContent + ' '
  }

  container.innerHTML = tmp += closingtag
  container.classList.add('paragraph--rendered')
}

const paragraph = document.querySelectorAll('.paragraph')
paragraph.forEach((p) => {
    wrapLines(p)
})
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 20rem;
}

.paragraph__inner-text {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="paragraph">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, voluptate eaque temporibus et quos aut praesentium excepturi sapiente laboriosam itaque, dolorem minima expedita. Ut repellat voluptatum odio sint, enim eos eveniet facere asperiores qui quod mollitia nesciunt iure voluptate autem veniam culpa atque, fugiat dolorum minima, voluptates tempora magni architecto.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This involve bit of trick , in this case we have pre-determined line-height

In my sample, i decided **30px as my fixed line-height for the paragraph**, then i create simple 1px x30px png image like this:

[image]

then use the image as background-image with this following code snipplet:

```css
  .container{
        background-image: url('https://img.techpowerup.org/200804/dottedline.png');
        background-repeat: repeat;
        background-size:1px 30px;
        background-position: bottom;
        overflow:hidden;
         box-sizing: border-box;

         box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    }

    .paragraph{
        line-height: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="paragraph">
            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
        </div>
    </div>
```

watch that i use *box-shadow: inset* css in container to hide the last border of the paragraph.

if you decide to change the lineheight, just change the image height and the line height.

*oh, its also responsive my dudes..*

Comment: Nice! For me a bummer is that the line goes all the way out. Also not sure how this would act in a situation when using fluid typography where the line-height isn't "fixed".

Comment: the case of line height not fixed is very rare on my experience so far

Comment: I come across fluid typography from time to time, we use it. Maybe there is away to solve that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

If the container has fixed width, you can wrap the text in div ,and set the "text-decoration" property to "underline", and wrap the last line in span tag and set its "text-decoration" property to "none".

**NOTE:** Only the last line must be wrapped inside span tag, and the "display" property of span tag must be set to "inline-block".

```css
.paragraph {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.last {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraph">
  Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown
  fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick
  brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown
  <span class="last">fox jumps over the lazy dog</span>
</div>
```

Comment: try on full scree and the last line will be half underlined

Comment: Only the last line must be inside span tag. It is not a responsive solution. I tried on a smaller screen, and it worked fine there.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {

  width: 300px;

}

span {
     position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed pink;
  line-height: 48px;
  
   
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="span">How to increase the gap between text and underlining in CSS How to increase the gap between text and underlining in CSS How to increase the gap between text and underlining in CSS</span>
</div>
```